# New "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'xyz' between objects in different contexts"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

when trying to add Core Data Objects in a second NSManagedObjectContext, I get an error saying Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'info' between objects in different contexts.
However, the two entities are on the same context (at least, they should). The debuger gives the identical hex-number. What is wrong with this code?

```
-(void) loadHistoricalPrices
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// Create context on background thread
if(document!=NULL)
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = NULL;
    NSNotificationCenter *nc =NULL;

    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [document.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];


    // Register context with the notification center
    nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:context];

    NSEntityDescription * infoEntity;
    infoEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Info" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSEntityDescription * historyEntity;
    historyEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:context];



// fetching an object-array of info-entity, called result

    if([result count]>0)
    {

        NSArray * items;
       // getting items to insert into history-entity


        for(NSString * item in items)
        {
            NSArray * subs;
            subs=[item componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            if([subs count]>5)
            {
                    HistoryMO * newHistory;

                    newHistory = [[[HistoryMO alloc] initWithEntity:historyEntity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context] autorelease];
                    [newHistory setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[subs objectAtIndex:4] doubleValue]] forKey:@"course"];
[newHistory setValue:infoMO forKey:@"info"];

// >>>>> CRASHES HERE

            }                
        }
    }


    // merge data
    if([[[context persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores] count]>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"saving...");

        error=NULL;
        [context save:&error];
        if (!error) [context reset]; else NSLog(@"error saving historic prices %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        if (!error) NSLog(@"saved successfully");
    }

    [nc removeObserver:self];
    [context release];
}
[pool release];
}
```

Comment: If in your opinion the crash has been originated in

[newHistory setValue:infoMO forKey:@"info"];
you have to ensure newHistory and infoMO are NSManagedObject in the same NSManagedObjectContext.

According to your code newHistory is a newly created NMO in the NMOC context, but I can not see any information about infoMO. Where is it created/passed?

Answer (score 1):

If infoMO is from the same context it gets invalidated after you call [context reset] in the following line:

`if (!error) [context reset]; else NSLog(@"error saving historic prices %@",[error localizedDescription]);`

So you need to refetch it. That is why ChrisH's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where's `infoMO` coming from? It looks like it's happening where you have the `// getting items to insert into history-entity` comment. My guess is you are using a different context to fetch these objects. You have to use the same context to lookup your `infoMO` objects as the one you are using to insert into the `HistoryMO`, or else the context can't manage the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your code sample, but based on your crash information, your `infoMO` object is from another context. You cannot create a relationship between two objects from different contexts.

The simplest solution is to get a reference to the infoMO in the current context by using NSManagedObject's objectID property.

Assuming that your infoMO instance is of the Info class, you'd do this:

```
Info *contextInfoMO = [context objectWithID:infoMO.objectID];
[newHistory setValue:contextInfoMO forKey:@"info"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. The comment "fetching an object-array..." is a shortcut for          
        
        NSPredicate * predicate;
        NSArray * result;
        NSError * error;
        NSFetchRequest * fetch;

        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"symbol = %@",self.symbol];

        fetch = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [fetch setEntity:infoEntity];
        [fetch setPredicate:predicate];
    
        result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
        
where the context is *the same* as used later in historyMO.

Comment: Ah OK, so you've got an array of Info objects...where does the infoMO instance get created? Presumably it's one of the objects in the array?

Comment: oops, sorry. This line is not listed. InfoMO is derived from the fetched array. After line "if([result count]>0)" the two lines are coded: InfoMO * infoMO;
            infoMO = (InfoMO *) [result objectAtIndex:0]; This code works fine for a small number of inserted objects. Is it a problem to quit the thread? Maybe, not every object has been inserted before releasing the context? And: by the way: is it possible to put code-format to answers in this forum?

Comment: today, with identical code, there is no error thrown. However, on large numbers of items to add, [context save:&error] returns "Could not merge changes. It sounds like a problem with the context, which will be released at the end of the thread. Do you have any suggestions, how to solve it? For the error ahead (Illegal attempt...) I suppose there is a bug in Mountain Lion.

Comment: funny. Now the "Illegal attempt" error is thrown again. Nothing changed.

Comment: What happens if you try the code I posted? Does the crash go away? It's hard to know what's causing this without seeing all of the code.

Comment: The program does not crash anymore, if the "save" is done at the end of the thread and not after each inserted item. By now - without changing the code, just positioning the merge-block at the end - it works all fine. However, when inserting a larger number of items at once, I get the [context save:&error] error "Could not merge changes." For only a few items (I guess < 100) it works all fine. I´m going mad with this!

Comment: Oh hold on, are you merging in the same thread? You need to be doing the merge on the main thread. It's hard to see from the code you posted, but I was assuming the `// merge data` stuff was happening in a separate method.

Comment: yes, but the thread runs it´s own method, what is:- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [document managedObjectContext];
    
    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:YES];
}

Comment: So saving is in fact done on main thread. I´ve output the numbers of items to add. Sometmies more than 3000 items are added without problems and than on another call with other items, a save with 1000 items failed (could not merge). I have tried to comment the setting of some properties out in order to test wether the managed object wasn´t created properly, but that also does not help. However: I do not get those illegal attempt to establish a relationship... message anymore.

Comment: I have got it! The problem was another thread, which performed merges aswell. I thought it does not mind as merging and merging again did not result in a successful saved file. If the failure was caused by other threads (now I know, it is), the merge should sometimes be performed successfully if only tried enough. So next question is: how to prevent the secont thread from saving?

Comment: Now runs pretty well. Thanx a lot for the comments